# Returning a new function instead of an object in factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a drawback instead of returning an object?

```
.factory('box', function(){
    var box = (function(){
        var privateVar;
        return {
            watch: {
                song: undefined,
                artist: undefined,
                id: undefined
            },
            update: function() {

            }
        }

    });


    return new box;
})
```

The reason I want to do it this way is so that function can function with prototype and use this.

Answer (score 0):

No there isnt any draw back, you can also use and take advantage of `this` in the returning function

```
.factory('example', ['$http', function($http) {
  return function(a, b) {
   this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
 };
}]);
```

and you can make an object outside also

```
var one = new example('A', 'B');
```